# Django Model ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models

If I want to add a Foreignkey to a model from another class in the same model e.g.

```
class1 (models.Model):
    variable1 = models.IntegerField()
class2 (models.Model):
    variable2 = models.CharField()
    foreignkey = models.Foreignkey(class1.variable1)
```

Is that possible? 
Does that make sense as a programming move?

This ForeignKey would be an ID Number (like a primary key) that I would like to import to other classes as well.

@ Manoj Govindan:

e.g.

```
class author(models.Model):
    authorlabel= models.IntegerField() # With choices
    ...

class books(models.Model):
    books=models.CharField()
    foreignkey= models.Foreignkey(author.authorlabel)
```

So that I have that data available in that table(?)/model as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
models.ForeignKey(class1, to_field = 'variable1')
```

Relevant documentation is [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field).

> This ForeignKey would be an ID Number (like a primary key) that I would like to import to other classes as well.

Not sure what you mean by this. Can you rephrase it and add an example?

Comment: The "key" with keys is that they uniquely identify a tuple in the relation (
"a row in the table"). So the *to_field* has to be **unique**.

AFAIK you can't define compound keys as a to_field, but I haven't tried. Has anyone ever used unique_together and pass an Iterable as the to_field? The singular in the parameter name suggests you'll get an Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to **Manoj Govindan**'s answer...

> This ForeignKey would be an ID Number (like a primary key) that I would like to import to other classes as well.

No it do not have to be a number, it can be a string, a datetime value or something else... But it have to be **unique**.